# Is it possible to load and index genomic data (Sequence Reads / VCF output etc.,) on Snowflake?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema, snowflake-task

I am looking for possibilities to load sequence data and VCF output data on Snowflake. The Snowflake website does indicate that it is possible to transform VCF format to semi-structured format like JSON or CSV before loading them but does not give much information about its capabilities in handling the information from Sequence reads and indexing them for querying. Any information on this would be helpful.

Comment: If you google "vcf format relational database" you'll find reams of research documents on this topic. You don't really have a specific question here

Comment: Yes, Snowflake has sample code and schemas available on-request for consuming and querying single-sample and multi-sample VCF and GVCF data sets, as well as annotations.  Best to reach out to a Snowflake directly (e.g. your account rep.) for more details.